# Cosmos DB query MIN function to get the smallest id

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a collection of documents. I would like to find document with smallest id.
I tried to run the query:

```
SELECT min(c.id) FROM c
```

But it returns an error.
[image]
The Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer does not allow to copy this text, therefore i pasted an image.
How to return the smallest id?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Without the error message I couldn't say more, but if you only want to retrieve the smallest id, you should query as follows:
`SELECT VALUE min(c.id) FROM c`

Comment: I have updated the question with an error message. It is impossible to copy the text from the Storage Explorer standalone tool I am using, therefore an image.

Comment: @DSpirit that is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to access a value only, use the `VALUE` keyword as follows:

```
SELECT VALUE min(c.id) FROM c
```

Especially when it comes to cross-partition queries this is required, as else the request would fail.

Comment: (Adding this as a real answer, as I was not sure if I got the question right before :))